# R map not showing latitude or longitude axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on creating a map in R and am following the [tutorial from the r-spatial website](https://r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf.html). When I make the map of the globe the latitude and longitude axes values do not appear. How can I make sure they appear?

```
library("ggplot2")
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf()
```

Below is the map that is produced from the code above.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show latitude and longitude we could use `coord_sf()`

```
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-180, 180), ylim = c(-90, 90), expand = FALSE)
```